# Why are OddSeq and SquareSeq Undefined?

Tags: c++, sequence

Do I need to use #include in order to define these variables? I was wondering why I was getting an error that says they are undefined. Other than that I believe the program came out the way I wanted it to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class AbstractSeq {
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;

    int main() {

        OddSeq odd;
        SquareSeq sq;
        int k;
        int m;
        

        cout << "Enter the lower bound integer k: ";
        cin >> k;

        cout << "Enter the upper bound integer m: ";
        cin >> m;

        cout << "The terms of the odd numbers sequence are: " << endl;
        odd.printSeq(k, m);

        cout << "Their sum is: ";
        cout << odd.sumSeq(k, m);



        cout << "The terms of the square numbers sequence are: " << endl;
        odd.printSeq(k, m);

        cout << "Their sum is: ";
        cout << sq.sumSeq(k, m);
        return 0;
    }

};
```

Comment: I'm as confused as your compiler. What are OddSeq and SquareSeq? Where did you define them? Why is main doing inside AbstractSeq?

Comment: How would I define those variables?

Comment: Were you provided with files to include or are you supposed to implement them yourself? I assume this is some sort of exercise.

Comment: The idea is to implement them myself, but I don't know where to go from here. Also yes, this is an assignment for one of my courses.

Comment: You need to create two classes that are derived from `AbstractSeq` and implement the functionality as specified by your assignment. Right now you're the only one with the details of the assignment so it's going to be difficult for anyone here to help you with anything specific. You will need to move your `main` function to a different cpp file since it will need to include the files with all of the different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few things.

First, yes, you probably need to `#include` some `.h` files. They won't appear magically.

Next, it's odd to put a main() inside a class. This isn't Java. Without trying it, I don't know if that's even legal. But if you're just trying to create a main like you would in Java, get rid of the containing class definition.

Comment: What what I need to include in order to define those variables? Is there some sort of sequence that needs to be included?

Comment: Those don't appear to be standard names, so you probably have some code related to it. Perhaps you should start learning C++ on something simpler.